# Maximum sum of subarray algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I thought of an algorithm to solve the maximum subarray but I am not sure how time and space efficient it is. Can anyone critique the code?

This is what I did:

1. condense the array(in the sense that you combine all contiguous positive and contiguous negative numbers together so that you end up with an array with alternating positive and negative numbers)
2. find the largest number in the condensed array
3. pair up positive and negative numbers together starting from the largest number and excluding the largest number(so if the largest number is index 3 in an array of length 7, index 2 and 1 will be paired, 0 will be alone, 4 and 5 will be paired, 6 will be alone.
4. recur over and over again until 2 end cases:
   a. length of the array becomes 2(guaranteed to be a positive and negative number, so just take the positive number)
   b. length of array becomes 3(alternates between positive and negative number e.g. pos neg pos or neg pos neg, so just take the largest number of the 3)

```
def condenseArray(nums):
    nums = [i for i in nums if i != 0]  
    
    condensedArray = [nums[0]]
    del nums[0]
    for i in nums:
        if (condensedArray[-1] > 0 and i > 0) or (condensedArray[-1] < 0 and i < 0):
            condensedArray[-1] += i 
        else:
            condensedArray.append(i)

    return condensedArray

def pairposandneg(nums):
    pairedArray = []
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if i%2 == 0 and i != len(nums) - 1:
            pairedArray.append(nums[i] + nums[i+1])
        elif i%2 == 0 and i == len(nums) - 1:
            pairedArray.append(nums[i])

    return pairedArray



def maxSubArray1(nums):

    if len(nums) == 2:
        return max(nums)
    elif len(nums) == 3:
        if len(condenseArray(nums)) == len(nums):
            return max(nums)
    nums = condenseArray(nums)
    max_num = max(nums)
    index_of_max_num = nums.index(max_num)

    subarray1 = pairposandneg(nums[:index_of_max_num][::-1])[::-1]
    subarray2 = pairposandneg(nums[index_of_max_num + 1:])
    nums = subarray1 + [max_num] + subarray2
    return maxSubArray1(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure if I understood your algorithm correctly, but it looks like it doesn't give correct results, e.g. for the example input below it gives me 16, where the correct answer is 25:

```
9 -1 9 -1 9 -100 10 -100 2 -1 2 -1 2
```

The time complexity is `O(n*lg n)`.

Comment: Yeah I algorithm on your example input and it did not work... thanks for helping anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the problem in another way...

Known that...
You got an 'array' and you want a 'sub_array'
`sum(sub_array)' is the result you are looking for :)

Condensing it with the positive and negative might not be necessary

For calculation... i will denote `sub_array` as `array.sub_array(start,end)`

```
sum(array.sub_array(start,end)) = sum(array.sub_array(start,array.length))-sum(array.sub_array(end+1,array.length))
```

Therefore, using simple logic

```
max_sum(array.sub_array(start,end)) = max(sum(array.sub_array(start,array.length)))-min(sum(array.sub_array(end+1,array.length)))
```

which `min(sum(array.sub_array(end+1,array.length))) = 0` if `end+1 == array.length`, as the index is reaching the end of the array :)

This is an O(n^2) algorithm, I believe.

To make it faster in time complexity...
Just pre-compute the `sum(array.sub_array((each index),array.length))` into another array. Then it is O(n)

I think the art of dynamic programming is to formulate a problem and eliminate the repeating steps.

Of course, if your data got a very repeating pattern, condensing positives and negatives could save up some space. Which would be very helpful in reducing the number "n".

But I think focusing on precomputed products could help you more with dynamic programming if you value time complexity. I think the key is to properly formulate your problem. Then try factorizing some reused functions. Would be easier than aiming a super-fast algorithm :)

Please tell me if I got something wrong haha. New to the forum hehe :)

Comment: It seems like your method does work, thank you for your help!

Comment: Hahaha good luck for your journey here :)